# Radio Buttons do not appear on site

Tags: html, css

I have no CSS files, only an index.html. I am following a youtube tutorial and I've confirmed multiple times that I am writing the code correctly. The video is a year old, so maybe, I'm doing something wrong syntactically. But otherwise, I cannot seem to find out why the radio buttons won't show up. I tried style="opacity: 100;" and that did nothing either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"
    />

    <title>PusherPoll</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>OS Vote</h1>
      <p>Vote for your favorite OS to develop on.</p>

      <form id="vote-form">
        <p>
          <input type="radio" name="os" id="windows" value="Windows" />
          <label for="windows">Windows</label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="radio" name="os" id="macos" value="MacOS" />
          <label for="macos">MacOS</label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="radio" name="os" id="linux" value="Linux" />
          <label for="linux">Linux Distro</label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="radio" name="os" id="other" value="Other" />
          <label for="other">Something Else</label>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Vote" class="btn" />

        <br></br>

        <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width:100%;"></div>


      </form>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pusher/5.0.2/pusher.min.js" integrity="PRIVATE-NOSHARE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js" integrity="sha256-CIc5A981wu9+q+hmFYYySmOvsA3IsoX+apaYlL0j6fg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you able to replicate the problem in codepen, jsbin etc or using the stackoverflow equivalent and add he link in the question? I just tried to run it but I'm missing main.js

Comment: They do appear without the materialize.css library. Read the documentation and update your HTML accordingly https://materializecss.com/radio-buttons.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the Materilize documentation, you should do it a bit different. Instead of this:

```
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="os" id="windows" value="Windows" />
  <label for="windows">Windows</label>
</p>
```

try this:

```
<p>
  <label>
    <input name="group1" type="radio" checked />
    <span>Red</span>
  </label>
</p>
```

Here is the documentation: [Radio buttons](https://materializecss.com/radio-buttons.html)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

your prbolem is in link rel

```
   <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"
    />
```